# Import textured 3d model from .obj file to iOs OpenGl E.S 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0, texture-mapping, .obj

Im am currently trying to convert 3D models in .obj format with texture to Objective c compatible code and render them with OpenGL E.S. 2.0.

I am using [obj2opengl][1] from Heiko Behrens to convert the 3d model to a header file

The 3d model has UV Mapping with [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/130/boxtexture.jpg) texture image.

Everything is almost working, but somehow the textures are not rendered correctly and my cube shows up like [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/4/cubebk.png/).

I have tried all sorts of things but cannot figure out what i am doing wrong or i just don't get it.

Here is my code on how i render the cube:

```
unsigned int boxNumVerts = 36;

float boxVerts [] = {
  // f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1 4/4/1 
  -0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
  -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
  0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
  // f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1 4/4/1 
  -0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
  0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
  0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
  // f 5/5/2 6/6/2 7/7/2 8/8/2 
  -0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
  0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
  0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
  // f 5/5/2 6/6/2 7/7/2 8/8/2 
  -0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
  -0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
  0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
  // f 1/9/3 4/10/3 6/6/3 5/5/3 
  -0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
  0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
  0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
  // f 1/9/3 4/10/3 6/6/3 5/5/3 
  -0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
  -0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
  0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
  // f 4/11/4 3/12/4 7/7/4 6/6/4 
  0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
  0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
  0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
  // f 4/11/4 3/12/4 7/7/4 6/6/4 
  0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
  0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
  0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
  // f 3/13/5 2/14/5 8/8/5 7/7/5 
  0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
  -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
  -0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
  // f 3/13/5 2/14/5 8/8/5 7/7/5 
  0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
  0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
  -0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
  // f 2/2/6 1/1/6 5/5/6 8/8/6 
  -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
  -0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
  -0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
  // f 2/2/6 1/1/6 5/5/6 8/8/6 
  -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
  -0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
  -0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
};


float boxTexCoords [] = {
  // f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1 4/4/1 
  0.5016, 0.7508,
  0.2504, 0.7508,
  0.2504, 1.002,
  // f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1 4/4/1 
  0.5016, 0.7508,
  0.5016, 1.002,
  0.2504, 1.002,
  // f 5/5/2 6/6/2 7/7/2 8/8/2 
  0.5016, 0.4996,
  0.5016, 0.2484,
  0.2504, 0.2484,
  // f 5/5/2 6/6/2 7/7/2 8/8/2 
  0.5016, 0.4996,
  0.2504, 0.4996,
  0.2504, 0.2484,
  // f 1/9/3 4/10/3 6/6/3 5/5/3 
  0.7528, 0.4996,
  0.7528, 0.2484,
  0.5016, 0.2484,
  // f 1/9/3 4/10/3 6/6/3 5/5/3 
  0.7528, 0.4996,
  0.5016, 0.4996,
  0.5016, 0.2484,
  // f 4/11/4 3/12/4 7/7/4 6/6/4 
  0.5016, -0.00279999999999991,
  0.2504, -0.00279999999999991,
  0.2504, 0.2484,
  // f 4/11/4 3/12/4 7/7/4 6/6/4 
  0.5016, -0.00279999999999991,
  0.5016, 0.2484,
  0.2504, 0.2484,
  // f 3/13/5 2/14/5 8/8/5 7/7/5 
  -0.0008, 0.2484,
  -0.0008, 0.4996,
  0.2504, 0.4996,
  // f 3/13/5 2/14/5 8/8/5 7/7/5 
  -0.0008, 0.2484,
  0.2504, 0.2484,
  0.2504, 0.4996,
  // f 2/2/6 1/1/6 5/5/6 8/8/6 
  0.2504, 0.7508,
  0.5016, 0.7508,
  0.5016, 0.4996,
  // f 2/2/6 1/1/6 5/5/6 8/8/6 
  0.2504, 0.7508,
  0.2504, 0.4996,
  0.5016, 0.4996,
};
```

And my rendering code:

```
-(void)setup
{
    self.drawingMode = GL_TRIANGLES;
    vertexData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:boxVerts length:sizeof(float)*boxNumVerts*3];
    textureCoordinateData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:boxTexCoords length:sizeof(float)*boxNumVerts*2];
    //    vertexNormalData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:PrisonCellNormals length:sizeof(float)*PrisonCellNumVerts*3];
}

-(void)renderInScene:(FRPGScene *)_scene 
{
     if (texture != nil)
        {
            effect.texture2d0.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeReplace;
            effect.texture2d0.target = GLKTextureTarget2D;
            effect.texture2d0.name = texture.name;
            [effect.texture2d0 setEnabled:YES];
        }

        effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = self.modelviewMatrix;
        effect.transform.projectionMatrix = _scene.projectionMatrix;

        [effect prepareToDraw];

        // setup
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);

        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);

        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, self.vertices);

        if (!useConstantColor)
        {
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
            glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, self.vertexColors);
        }

        if (texture != nil)
        {
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
            glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, self.textureCoordinates);
        }

        glDrawArrays(drawingMode, 0, self.numVertices);

        glDisable(GL_BLEND);

        // teardown
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);

        if (!useConstantColor)
        {
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
        }

        if (texture != nil)
        {
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
        }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The appDelegate function where i set up my context.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    EAGLContext *context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

    GLKView *view = [[GLKView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] context:context];
    view.delegate = self; //Makes sure the views drawInRect is called

    FRPGViewController *controller = [[FRPGViewController alloc] init];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.view = view;

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = controller;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    scene = [[FRPGTestLevel alloc] init];

    //Set screen aspect ratio boundaries ipad 4:3 iphone 3:2
    CGRect rect = view.bounds;

    scene.left = -100.0f;
    scene.right = 100.0f;
    scene.bottom = -100.0f / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height); // -75.0..
    scene.top = 100.0f / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height); // 75.0..
    [scene setup];

    [controller setScene:scene];


    return YES;
}
```

My Scenes render function clears the buffer and calls the above renderInScene method on every object

```
-(void)render
{
     glClearColor(clearColor.r, clearColor.g, clearColor.b, clearColor.a);
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     [object renderInScene:scene]; 
}
```

Comment: You should post your code for setting up the OpenGL context.  Do you have a depth buffer at all?  I notice that you are not *clearing* your depth buffer.  That call to glClear should look like `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

Comment: To me this looks like a front/back problem. I have not gone through all of your vertices but you should make sure that you define all polygons in a counter-clockwise order to tell OpenGL that this is the front side of the polygon. Try using backface culling to not draw back sides of polygons by using `glCullFace(GL_BACK);` and `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);`

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have updated my post and added the context creation. I tried the cull face settings as you suggested but this gives me an even stranger effect. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/27/test2ic.png/

Comment: `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);`

Comment: Thank you Dan and Aaron, now every time i render an object with texture i do a glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE) before render and a glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE) after render of the object. This is working nicely!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your depth buffer

```
GLuint _depthRenderBuffer;

- (void)setupDepthBuffer
{
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_depthRenderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
}
```

and then add to your frame buffer

```
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBuffer);
```